# Is there a way to track requests sent to couchbase server via sdk

Tags: php, node.js, couchbase

I wanted to know if there is a way to track what requests being sent to couchbase server via sdk.

For example: If I am sending and upsert() / save() request to save the document, then is there a way to track that request as to what is being sent and if there are any issues where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: Is this PHP or node or both?

Comment: Probably a silly question but have you checked the logs ? http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/Trbl-logs.html

Answer (score 1):

There is not any particular way to track the specific requests that an SDK is dispatching to the server.  You should be getting any errors that occur back as a response through the language though.  For PHP this would mean that the operation will be throwing an exception, and in Node.js you will get the error back as the first parameter of the callback function.